# How to show logo on front page of Paginated Report in header and hide it in following pages

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0, powerbi-paginated-reports

I want to show the logos in header section only on the front page of the Paginated Report, In rest of the Page it should be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Logo or header and Go to the Properties --> Visibilty -->show or hide based on Expression -->
Give the condition "IIF(Globals!PageNumber=1,false,true)"

[image]